# accessing relations within prolog

Tags: prolog, relation, relational

In my discrete mathematics course, we have a single prolog assignment that goes as follows

> Create a program that models students, classes, rooms, dates, and
> their relations. Include relevant functions

My initial thought was that there needs to be generated a lot of data, and I am still curious whether this assignment can be completed without explicitly mapping every single relation explicitly.

Apparently it seemed as if there were two strategies, to use a graph (seemed complex) or use this mapping strategy `relation(value, value2)` (I want to call it a predicate, but I am not sure if that is right).

However I can't seem to figure out how to access the relations within the rules? (I mean the :- syntax, seems more like functions to me than rules)

I feel like I am on a sidetrack, I have issues finding the information I need to solve this problem since I have difficulties with the terminology.

```
%student(name, class, semester)
student(søren, 101, 1).
student(jens, 101, 1).
student(peter, 101, 2).
student(eskild, 101, 1).
student(jørgen, 101, 2).
student(signe, 101, 1).
student(pernille, 101, 2).
student(katrine, 101, 2).
student(sophie, 101, 1).
student(liva, 101, 1).
%semester_subjects(semester, subject)
semester_subjects(2, DM).
semester_subjects(1, test).
semester_subjects(2, BI).
semester_subjects(1, SI).
semester_subjects(1, LSD).
semester_subjects(2, SI).
semester_subjects(2, LSD).
%class(name, subject)
class(101, DM).
class(101, test).
class(101, SI).
class(101, LSD).
class(101, BI).
%schedule(weekday(0-6), subject)
schedule(0, test).
schedule(1, test).
schedule(1, BI).
schedule(2, SI).
schedule(2, LSD).
schedule(4, DM).

%has_class_today(student_name, day) :-.
%has_sudent(class, student_name) :-.
%has_subject(student_name, subject_name) :-.
```

I feel like I should be able to do something like

```
has_class_today(student_name, day) :- {
    Class = student(søren).class
    Semester = student(søren).semester
    SemesterSubjects = semester_subjects.forAll( if(semester == Semester) return subject)
    SubjectsToday = schedule(day).forAll(if(SemesterSubjects.includes(subject))
    if(SubjectsToday > 0) return true
    else return false                               
}
```

But I relaly cannot figure out how to do so. To summarize my question.

**Should my current aproach work how can I retrieve the values of one relation (Peter <-> Susan) based on the other?
If my current approach does not work, how would you suggest to tackle this assignment**

Comment: When you write `semester_subjects(2, DM).` you are saying that `DM` is a variable. If you want it to be an atom you have to write `semester_subjects(2, dm).`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's hard to explain and needs at least 2 hours of instruction.

This is a standard database modelling assignment.

You have the "objects"

- *student* with attributes *name*, *class*, *semester*

Which is modelled by the *predicate* `student/3` in Prolog. In [relational database terminology / the relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model), this is called a *relation* or a *table*.

Appears differently (imagine it is in tabular form), but ... same thing.

You have the "elided objects"

- *semester* with attribute *semester id*, with values 1 or 2
- *subject* with attribute *subject name*, with with values `DM`, `test` etc..

which are not listed explicitly using a predicate (though that would be possible, and recommended depending on the application) as in:

```
semester(1).
semester(2).
subject("DM").
subject("test").
```

Instead these objects are implicitly listed by giving a 2-place relationship between them

- *semester* related to *subject* via *semester_subjects*

and this is modelled through the predicate (aka relation) `semester_subjects/2`.

etc.

(Note that you code is erroneous. Prolog will consider anything starting with an uppercase letter as a variable, so you have to type `"DM"` or `'DM'` rather than `DM`.)

Go to [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) and enter your data.

```
% The student relation: student(name, class, semester)
% A predicate made up by a set of facts.

student('søren', 101, 1).
student('jens', 101, 1).
student('peter', 101, 2).
student('eskild', 101, 1).
student('jørgen', 101, 2).
student('signe', 101, 1).
student('pernille', 101, 2).
student('katrine', 101, 2).
student('sophie', 101, 1).
student('liva', 101, 1).

% The relation expressing the connection/relationship  
% between semester and subjects
% semester_subjects(semester, subject)
% A predicate made up by a set of facts.

semester_subjects(2, 'DM').
semester_subjects(1, 'test').
semester_subjects(2, 'BI').
semester_subjects(1, 'SI').
semester_subjects(1, 'LSD').
semester_subjects(2, 'SI').
semester_subjects(2, 'LSD').

% The relation expressing the connection/relationship  
% between class and subject
% class(name, subject)
% A predicate made up by a set of facts.

class(101, 'DM').
class(101, 'test').
class(101, 'SI').
class(101, 'LSD').
class(101, 'BI').

% The relation expressing the connection/relationship  
% between weekday and subject
% schedule(weekday(0-6), subject)
% A predicate made up by a set of facts.

schedule(0, 'test').
schedule(1, 'test').
schedule(1, 'BI').
schedule(2, 'SI').
schedule(2, 'LSD').
schedule(4, 'DM').
```

Once that is done, you can ask *queries*:

For example:

`student(SNAME,CLASS_ID,SEMESTER),class(CLASS_ID,CLASS_NAME).`

which means:

Retrieve all the tuples "SNAME,CLASS_ID,SEMESTER,CLASS_NAME" where you can juxtapose an element of the `student` relation (or, a fact of the `student` predicate) and an element of the `class` relation (or, a fact of the `class` predicate) such that the value `CLASS_ID` appears in both identically those as stated. This is evidently a [database JOIN operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

You can then repack that query by defining a new predicate with a single clause in which the values that interest you appear:

`interesting(SNAME,CLASS_NAME) :- student(SNAME,CLASS_ID,SEMESTER),class(CLASS_ID,CLASS_NAME).`

and add it to the program.

Once that is done, you can issue new queries of the form

`interesting(S,C).`

In the end, you need to try this yourself. It's the only way.

[image: SWISH example]